# What return types to use for an ajax form submission?

Tags: javascript, json, validation

I have a "New Post" form which is modal in the UI.  When the user submits it, an ajax call posts it to the New Post action in my Content controller.  My question is, what should the controller's response types be?

- If the form validates I would like to give the UI the thumbs up so it can close the modal window and get on with things.  I suspect that JSON would be a better choice here, since introspecting HTML is not as clean.
- If the form does not validate I need to return replacement HTML (which is the form re-rendered including error messages).

I am leaning towards always returning a JSON object.  The first property would be a boolean success/failure indicator.  If the insert has failed, there would be a second property which contains the replacement HTML.

Does this sound reasonable?  Are there better alternatives?

I am using jQuery and Zend Framework (not that it makes much difference to the answer).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer to your question: JSON.

And you don't have to return html via the ajax response, you could handle the messaging via DOM elements, something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "login.php",
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.field.status == 'failure') {
            if (data.field.username == 'fail') {
                $("div#usernameError").show();
            }
            if (data.field.password == 'fail') {
                $("div#passwordError").show();
            }
        } else {
            $("div#loginOverlay").dialog("close");
        }
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: Hey Mike, that's really nice.  Thanks.

Comment: np. You could even expand it so the json includes why the password entry was invalid; no match, too low char count, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these two JSON responses:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "fields": ["username", "password"],
    "message": "Please enter valid username and password"
}
```

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "redirect": "http:/who.cares/form/complete"
}
```

Instead of replacing the whole form, I would recommend to have a response, that only replies with the important bits.

Beside, every time you use `innerHTML`, gods kill a kitten .. and also your DOM structure and references are destroyed. Makes for very fragile JS code.